# Pyramid: How to config multiple methods of a class as different views

Tags: python, pyramid

I simply want this to work, but it doesn't:

```
class Test12:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name='test1')
    def test1(self):
        return Response('I am from test 1')

    @view_config(route_name='test2')
    def test2(self):
        return Response('Hi there from test2')


config.add_route('test1', '/test1')
config.add_route('test2', '/test2')
```

For both URLs `/test1` and `/test2` -- the response returned by the `test2()` method is returned. How should I get this to work correctly? (Or am I missing something here?)

Comment: http://SSCCE.org - It would help if you could provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are seeing.

Comment: I don't need to. Pyramid programmers will understand this pretty easily.

Comment: @good_computer, fill out this template for a single file app: https://gist.github.com/thapar/5218205 . People will be more willing to help you when they see a live question (even non-Pyramid people could more easily help). You can run it from the command-line with `python single_file_app.py`

Comment: If you aren't on Python 3, then at least make sure your class inherits from `object`. Other than that, your pasted code should work.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel I am on Python 3 so I don't need object. The above code does NOT work, probably because I have two routes pointing to the methods of the same class -- and I guess we only have one attr argument that specifies what method of the class to call. I am right here? I think one class can only serve on route name (although with different predicates, you can have multiple methods of the class responding the the same route name)

Comment: See, you say that.. but I created this example that works perfectly fine by copy/pasting your code. https://gist.github.com/mmerickel/5219488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely issue is a flaw in your original (and not pasted) code wherein you accidentally named the two methods with the same name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It runs. I'll see what I was doing wrong and post the reason here. Thanks, meanwhile.

Comment: I guess there was some ACL/permissions related glitch or probably some route naming mistake. But I still don't understand, then, what's the `attr` for. Is it only useful when you put the decorator on the class and not on the method?

Comment: Yep. You can use `attr` when decorating the class itself, to avoid it defaulting to `__call__`.